# ZXing Barcode Scanner preview width

Tags: java, android, zxing

I work with ZXing Barcode Application - I want to tune it so it fit my requirements. However all the time the preview image is a bit wider than real image. I've tried to look in `CameraConfigurationManager` and `CameraManager` classes, especially setting manualy screen/camera resolution in `initFromCameraParameters()` method of `CameraConfigurationManager`. Anyone got idea where to set it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've couldn't find the solution, however this problem appears only on Nexus 7 tablet on other devices (smartphones) it works well. If someone is interested in modifying the rectangle of the scanner app - look at constants of `CameraManager` class.
I've filled an [issue](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/483) on ZXing github, so let's see what they'll say